# Coded UI Throws "Unable to load one or more of the requested types"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, coded-ui-tests, visual-studio-debugging

I am unable to get *Coded UI* debugging to work. Visual Studio won't stop on a breakpoint. A simple demo test (which merely enters a number into an Excel worksheet cell) succeeds when it's run without debugging. But when debugging the test, the test runner errors immediately without attempting to step into the test-class constructor (if provided) or into the test-method.

The error reported is:

```
Message: Unit Test Adapter threw exception: 
Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information..
```

I'm running Visual Studio 2017, Version 15.5.0.

The Debug window's output:

```
'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TESTPLATFORM\testhost.x86.exe'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: testhost.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TESTPLATFORM\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CoreUtilities.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: testhost.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TESTPLATFORM\Microsoft.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: testhost.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TESTPLATFORM\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'testhost.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: testhost.x86.exe): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TESTPLATFORM\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

...

'QTAgent32_40.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: TestAppDomain: 0bb1983f-0f53-41cc-b4ed-143874102a64): Unloaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2017\ENTERPRISE\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\TESTPLATFORM\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel.dll'
'QTAgent32_40.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: TestAppDomain: 0bb1983f-0f53-41cc-b4ed-143874102a64): Unloaded 'C:\VST\CodedUITestProject2\TestResults\abcdef_X#XXX## 2017-12-05 11_05_06\Out\CodedUITestProject2.dll'
The thread 0x1860 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1dcc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadInterruptedException' in mscorlib.dll
The thread 0x1cb0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2d54 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2a40 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1e04 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8104] QTAgent32_40.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1714 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x265c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[8104] QTAgent32_40.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2d9c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xde4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x3bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x253c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[12012] testhost.x86.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[12012] testhost.x86.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I've tried repaving Visual Studio and installing the latest bits, etc. to no avail. And I'm experiencing this issue on two different machines.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue after upgrading to 15.5 today.

Comment: @CalvinDale, What about this issue? Product team provided the solution in the feedback submitted by me, if possible, please check it.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT No, unfortunately setting the machine environment variable __UNITTESTEXPLORER_VSINSTALLPATH__ didn't work for me.

Comment: @CalvinDale, Do you update your VS to 15.5.1? Do you restart your VS after you set the environment variable? I just update my answer, if possible, you could check it.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, Yes, I'm running 15.5.1

Comment: @CalvinDale, Could you share a screen shot about the  System environment variable in your windows? Do you use the Windows 10 64 bit? I set the value __UNITTESTEXPLORER_VSINSTALLPATH__ (two underscores), it works well in my windows 10 64 bit. VS2017 was installed in C:\Program Files (x86). I have to restart the VS. Maybe you could also test it using VS as the admin.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, It doesn't appear to be possible to add a screenshot to a comment. Here's what I have `__UNITTESTEXPLORER_VSINSTALLPATH__ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE`

Comment: @CalvinDale, You could add it in your previous issue, we really couldn't add it to the comment. What is your Windows Environment like my previous reply? I really could debug it in my side even if I got the same issue as your before. Maybe we would think about the windows Environment or others, do you test it using other VS2017 machine?

Comment: @CalvinDale, Does it have this issue using the latest VS2017 15.5.2 version?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, Upgrading to v15.5.2 resolved the issue. I simultaneously upgraded all extensions to their latest version (which may or may not have been related to this issue's resolution). On my system, three extensions required upgrading: Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools, Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools, and SQL Prompt Core.

Comment: @CalvinDale, Glad to know that it has been resolved, if so, I updated my answer, if it is helpful for you, you could mark it as the answer, so we could close this case. Have a nice day:)

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, While upgrading VS to v15.5.2 certainly resolved this issue for me, it's not clear that upgrading fixes it every time. Refer to Boris-Bucha's comment and Ewan's comment below.

Comment: @CalvinDale, Do you also add that System environment variable after you update it to the latest 15.5.2 version? Actually I test it in my windows 10, it still has this issue using the latest version, I just could resolve it in my side using the environment variable now. And the product team also provide this workaround.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Yes, I do (still) have the environment variable set. However it didn't work for me using the previous Visual Studio version.

Answer (score 1):

I use the latest VS2017 15.5, it really has this issue:

[image]

But in other VS version or VS 2017 15.4.4,it really has no this issue.

Since I could repro this issue, I help you report this feedback to the product team here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/161803/cant-debug-coded-ui-test-in-latest-vs2017.html

If possible, you could add your comment and vote this feedback.

**Update:**

I update my VS2017 to 15.5.1 version, and then set the System environment variable like the following screen shot, Note: Your VS2017 would be installed to the path like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE. And then I restart the VS IDE and reopen the test project, I could debug it well now.

Since the latest VS version was the 15.5.2, please also update it to the latest version.

[image]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bee9e7f1-5be8-4bee-981e-983b14f22faf/how-to-install-coded-ui-component-in-vs-2017-so-that-debugging-will-work?forum=vstest

Comment: Nope. I have 15.5.2. Does not work. Where are the times when MS was dog-fooding before the release .. :/

Comment: @Boris Bucha, Do you resolve it using the System environment variable?

Comment: Same issue with me even if I have set environment variable then also getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Then Debug mode On!

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was going in to my project settings and disabling Prefer 32-bit. I have no idea why this setting was enabled, but this resolved the issue for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I started experiencing this issue after upgrading VS 2017 to 15.5.2 (I think I might have skipped one update, so possibly could have been introduced in 15.5.1).

Updating environment variable didn't work for me, so for a number of days the only way I could debug was launching the debugger explicitly in the code as per Sergey's answer.

However, Visual Studio Update 2017 **15.5.3** has resolved the issue.